# Functions Returning A String - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm doing a fraction calculator and I'm trying to add 2 fractions when I put in my fractions it just adds my Whole numbers only and nothing else if my fraction is 2 3/4 + 2 3/5 it add the whole numbers and outputs 4

```
    var firstStep = firstDenomInTextField! * firstWholeInTextField! / firstDenomInTextField!

    var secondStep = firstStep + firstNumInTextField! / firstDenomInTextField!

    var thirdStep = secondDenomInTextField! * secondWholeInTextField! / secondDenomInTextField!
    var fourthStep = thirdStep + secondNumInTextField! / secondDenomInTextField!

    var calculatedAnswer = (secondStep + fourthStep)
    var numerator = Int(calculatedAnswer * 10 * 10)
    println(numerator)
    answerLabel.hidden = false
    answerLabel.text = printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: numerator)
```

**printSimplifiedFraction Function**

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100) -> String
{
    var finalNumerator = numerator;
    var finalDenominator = denominator;

    var wholeNumbers:Int = numerator / denominator;
    var remainder:Int = numerator % denominator;

    //println("wholeNumbers = \(wholeNumbers), remainder = \(remainder)");
    //println("\(denominator) % \(remainder) = \(denominator % remainder)");

    if(remainder > 0)
    {
        // see if we can simply the fraction part as well
        if(denominator % remainder == 0) // no remainder means remainder can be simplified further
        {
            finalDenominator = denominator / remainder;
            finalNumerator = remainder / remainder;
        }
        else
        {
            finalNumerator = remainder;
            finalDenominator = denominator;
        }
    }

    if(wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder > 0)
    {
        // prints out whole number and fraction parts
        return("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers) \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)");
    }
    else if (wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder == 0)
    {
        // prints out whole number only
        return("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers)");
    }
    else
    {
        // prints out fraction part only
        return("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)");
    }
}
```

**My Question** I want to make it so it does not just add the whole numbers but add the whole fraction.
If you need any clarifications or questions please comment them down below

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve, but when you call the `printSimplifiedFraction` method, you are not passing it anything but the numerator...

Comment: when I put `printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: numerator, Denominator: 100)` it does the same thing

Comment: Obviously, as 100 is the default value you've put in your function-declaration.

Comment: So what are you supposed to return `5 7/20` ?

Comment: Dividing two integers returns an integer (i.e. it *truncates* the result), perhaps that is your problem? – (That is basic C and has been asked and answered many times ...)

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your problem? At what point do the variables not contain what you expect?

Comment: @MartinR when I add the second and fourth step together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with fractions, you should use Double instead of Int. Also when multiplying by 10 you should use 10.0 instead. Be careful you are mixing Int(Integers) with Double(fractions). Also when declaring vars as parameters if you omit it will be a constant by default, if you would like to change it you don't need a second var, just add var in front of it when declaring it there).
I think You should restart it from the beginning, Syntax is OK. Don't forget to convert from Int to Double when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your math is somewhat of in the code your present. The following code calculates the fraction and returns a string with the result.

```
    ...
    var wholeTotal = firstWholeInTextField! + secondWholeInTextField!
    var numeratorTotal = (firstNumInTextField! * secondDenomInTextField!) + (secondNumInTextField! * firstDenomInTextField!)
    let denominatorTotal = firstDenomInTextField! * secondDenomInTextField!
    while numeratorTotal > denominatorTotal {
        wholeTotal++
        numeratorTotal -= denominatorTotal
    }
    let resultString = simplifiedFractionStringWith(wholeTotal, numerator: numeratorTotal, denominator: denominatorTotal)
    answerLabel.text = ("The result is: " + resultString)


func simplifiedFractionStringWith(wholeNumber: Int, numerator: Int, denominator: Int) -> String {
    if numerator > 0 {
        return ("\(wholeNumber) \(numerator)/\(denominator)")
    } else {
        return ("\(wholeNumber)")
    }
}
```

That being said I *really* believe the whole thing is much better solved creating a fraction-struct...

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my other answer I think the whole thing would be much better solved by creating a `struct` for your fraction. As I (clearly) have no life, I've put together another example:

```
struct fraction {
   var wholeNumber = 0
   var numerator = 0
   var denominator = 0

   func asString()-> String {
      if numerator > 0 {
         return ("\(wholeNumber) \(numerator)/\(denominator)")
      } else {
         return ("\(wholeNumber)")
      }
   }

   func combinedWith(aFraction: fraction) -> fraction {
      var wholeTotal = wholeNumber + aFraction.wholeNumber
      var numeratorTotal = (numerator * aFraction.denominator) + (aFraction.numerator * denominator)
      let denominatorTotal = denominator * aFraction.denominator
      while numeratorTotal > denominatorTotal {
         wholeTotal++
         numeratorTotal -= denominatorTotal
      }
      let combinedFraction = fraction(wholeNumber: wholeTotal, numerator: numeratorTotal, denominator: denominatorTotal)
      return combinedFraction
   }
}
```

Then the code to show the total of two fractions would look something like this (in your app):

```
let firstFraction = fraction(wholeNumber: firstWholeInTextField!, numerator: firstNumInTextField!, denominator: firstDenomInTextField!)
let secondFraction = fraction(wholeNumber: secondWholeInTextField!, numerator: secondNumInTextField!, denominator: secondDenomInTextField!)
let combinedFraction = firstFraction.combinedWith(secondFraction)
answerLabel.text = ("The result is: " + combinedFraction.asString())
```